# append '#div-id' to reference a html element by id using htmlhelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper, html.actionlink

How do i append to an url like this

```
mysite.com/articles/1/my-first-article
```

the element with the div id #commentList

```
mysite.com/articles/1/my-first-article#commentList


<%: Html.ActionLink("text", "action", new {/* ??? HOW TO SET IT HERE ??? */})%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [proper overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx) (the one that takes a fragment) which will allow you to generate the desired url containing a fragment portion:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "some text",     // linkText
    "articles",      // actionName
    null,            // controllerName
    null,            // protocol
    null,            // hostName
    "commentList",   // fragment <-- that's what you need
    new { id = 1 },  // routeValues
    null             // htmlAttributes
) %>
```